# How to get .crt and .pem certificate files from .cer

Tags: ssl

I have `.cer` certificate which is not readable using text editor. I need to convert it to `.pem` and `.crt` in order to upgrade files on the server.

As I can see `.crt` file begins with `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----`

`.pem` file begins with `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`

Can I get both or these files from `.cer` file or do I need something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `.crt` and `.cer` files contain certificates, encoded as binary DER or ascii PEM
- `.pem` files can contain certificates or keys

See http://www.gtopia.org/blog/2010/02/der-vs-crt-vs-cer-vs-pem-certificates/

You can convert a binary `.cer` to `.pem` encoding the content in base64 and adding `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` header and `END CERTIFICATE` footer, but to get a `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` you will need a file with a private key. Typically `.key` file

Comment: do i need to check-in those files (.pem) to the code repository?